# Hartree equation in density matrix formalism is equivalent to a system of Hartree equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, density-function, quantum-mechanics

I want to prove that:

> If the density matrix $$\gamma(t):=\sum_{j=1}^N|u_j(t)\rangle\langle u_j(t)|=\sum_{j=1}^N\langle u_j(t),\cdot\rangle u_j$$ solves $$i\partial_t\gamma(t)=[-\Delta+w*\rho,\gamma],$$ then the $u_1,...,u_N$ solve the system $$i\partial _tu_j=(-\Delta+w*\rho)u_j,\qquad j=1,...,N,$$ where $\rho(t,x)=\sum_{j=1}^N|u_j(t,x)|^2$.

My attempt at proof:

Suppose the density matrix solves density matrix $\gamma(t):=\sum_{j=1}^N|u_j(t)\rangle\langle u_j(t)|=\sum_{j=1}^N\langle u_j(t),\cdot\rangle u_j$ solves $$i\partial_t\gamma(t)=[-\Delta+w*\rho,\gamma].$$ Then, denoting $H=-\Delta+w*\rho$,

\begin{align*}
(i\partial_t\gamma)u_i=i\sum_{j=1}^N({\langle{\partial_tu_j(t),u_i(t)}\rangle u_j(t)+\langle{u_j(t),u_i(t)}\partial_tu_j(t)})&=i\sum_{j=1}^N\langle{\partial_tu_j(t),u_i(t)}\rangle u_j(t)+i\partial_tu_i(t)\\
&=-i\sum_{j=1}^N \langle{u_j(t),\partial_tu_i}\rangle u_j(t)+i\partial_tu_i(t)\\
&=-\sum_{j=1}^N \langle {u_j(t),i\partial_tu_i}\rangle u_j(t)+i\partial_tu_i(t)\\
&=-\gamma(i\partial_tu_i)+i\partial_t(\gamma u_i)\\
&=[{i\partial_t,\gamma}]u_i.
\end{align*}

So because $i\partial_t\gamma=[{H,\gamma}]$, we deduce\begin{align*}
    0=[{i\partial_t-H,\gamma}]u_i=(i\partial_t-H)u_i-\gamma((i\partial_t-H)u_i)
\end{align*} But this is not enough...

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me slightly reformulate and extend your question: if $\gamma(t)$ is the solution to a (time-dependent) [Liouville-von Neumann equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix#The_Von_Neumann_equation_for_time_evolution)
$$
i\dot\gamma(t)=[H(t),\gamma(t)]\tag{1}
$$
and if this solution diagonalizes as $\gamma(t)=\sum_j|u_j(t)\rangle\langle u_j(t)|$ with $u_j(t)$ pairwise orthogonal, then you're asking whether
$$
i\dot u_j(t)=H(t)u_j(t)\tag{2}
$$
holds for all $j$. In other words your question in its current form asks:

> Given a state $\gamma(t)$ which evolves according to Liouville-von Neumann, is *every* eigenstate $u_j(t)$ of $\gamma(t)$ a solution to the [(time-dependent) Schrödinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C4%B6dinger_equation#Time-dependent_equation)?

The answer to this question is no (even for pure states); roughly speaking the problem is that you have to be careful when diagonalizing your state $\gamma(t)$. For a simple example consider $H$ to be the [Pauli matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices) $\sigma_z$ and
$$
\gamma(t)=\frac12\begin{pmatrix}1&e^{-2it}\\e^{2it}&1\end{pmatrix}=|u(t)\rangle\langle u(t)|\qquad\text{ for }u(t):=\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix} e^{-2it}\\1\end{pmatrix}\,.\tag{3*}
$$
One readily verifies that $\gamma(t)$ satisfies (1) when choosing $H(t)\equiv H$. However,
$$
i\dot u(t)=\sqrt2\begin{pmatrix}e^{-2it}\\0\end{pmatrix}\neq \frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix} e^{-2it}\\-1\end{pmatrix} =Hu(t)\,.
$$
The problem here is that each eigenstate $u_j$ can be replaced by $e^{it}u_j$ without changing $\gamma$: note that $|e^{it}u_j\rangle\langle e^{it}u_j|=e^{it}e^{-it}|u_j\rangle\langle u_j|=|u_j\rangle\langle u_j|$, but -- while the projector $|u_j\rangle\langle u_j|$ is unaffected by such a time-dependent phase -- the derivative of $e^{it}u_j$ may look very different from $\dot u_j$.
Indeed, decomposing
$$
\gamma(t)=\frac12\begin{pmatrix}1&e^{-2it}\\e^{2it}&1\end{pmatrix}=|v(t)\rangle\langle v(t)|\qquad\text{ where now }v(t):=\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix} e^{-it}\\e^{it}\end{pmatrix}
$$
(i.e. $v(t)=e^{it}u(t)$) we find
$$
i\dot v(t)=\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix} e^{-it}\\-e^{it}\end{pmatrix}=Hv(t)\tag{3}
$$
as desired. [NB: This is also the reason why your proof attempt did not lead anywhere: you assumed the $u_j(t)$ to be an *arbitrary* diagonalization of $\gamma(t)$ which as we just saw does *not* necessarily reduce to the Schrödinger equation]

> **Remark 1.** To affirm that the underlying problem is solely due to the fact that pure states (when expressed as vectors) have a degree of freedom in terms of any additional phase $e^{i\varphi}$, and has nothing to do with dynamics of any kind let us modify our example: Instead of $H=\sigma_z$ choose $H=\alpha(t)\sigma_z$ with $\alpha:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ any function (as long as the dynamics still exist, of course; mathematically this amounts to $\alpha$ being [locally integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_integrable_function)).
> Then the solution to
> $$
> i\dot\gamma(t)=[H(t),\gamma(t)]\qquad\gamma(0)=\frac12\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}
> $$
> is given by
> $$
> \gamma(t)=\frac12\begin{pmatrix}1& e^{-2i\int_0^t\alpha(\tau)\,d\tau  } \\  e^{2i\int_0^t\alpha(\tau)\,d\tau  }&1\end{pmatrix}\,.
> $$
> As expected this reproduces ($3^*$) when setting $\alpha(t)\equiv 1$.
> However the counterexample continues to work without further ado once $e^{it}$ is replaced by $e^{i\int_0^t\alpha(\tau)\,d\tau  }$.

> **Remark 2.** Interestingly, this problem even appears in the "trivial" case of one dimension because non-trivial phases (of state vectors) exist there, as well. There the only density matrix is $1$---so $\rho(t)=1$, no matter what $H$ is---but state vectors can take any value $e^{i\phi}$. With this one can construct a counterexample similar to the above: $H=1$ and $\rho(t)=1=|u(t)\rangle\langle u(t)|$ with $u(t):=e^{2it}$. Then $i\dot u(t)=-2e^{2it}\neq e^{2it}=Hu(t)$.

Either way the question we *should* ask is:

> Given $\gamma(t)$ *does there exist* a diagonalization $\gamma(t)=\sum_j|u_j(t)\rangle\langle u_j(t)|$ such that each $u_j$ solves the Schrödinger equation?

This statement turns out to be correct, and the key to proving this is to consider the operator lift of (2):
$$
i\dot U(t)=H(t)U(t)\tag{4}
$$
Given some initial state $\gamma_0$ and *any* unitary diagonalization, i.e. $\gamma_0=U_0D_0U_0^*$, $U_0$ unitary, $D_0=\operatorname{diag}(r_1,\ldots,r_n)$ diagonal
this shift in perspective yields a solution to (1):

> **Lemma.** Let $U(t)$ be the solution to (4) with initial condition $U(0)=U_0$. Then $\gamma(t)=U(t)D_0U(t)^*$ is the solution to (1) with initial condition $\gamma(0)=\gamma_0$.

While this is straightforward let us quickly verify this anyway.
The initial condition is met because $\gamma(0)=U(0)D_0U(0)^*=U_0D_0U_0^*=\gamma_0$. More importantly, the product rule yields
\begin{align*}
i\dot\gamma(t)&=i\dot U(t)D_0U(t)^*+iU(t)D_0\dot U(t)^*\\
&=i\dot U(t)D_0U(t)^*-U(t)D_0(i\dot U(t))^*\\
&\overset{(4)}=  H(t)U(t)D_0U(t)^*-U(t)D_0(H(t)U(t))^*\\
&=[H(t),U(t)D_0U(t)^*]=[H(t),\gamma(t)]
\end{align*}
so, indeed, (1) holds. $\square$

Now these propagators $U(t)$ "contain" the diagonalization you are looking for:

> **Theorem.** Define $ u_j(t):=\sqrt{r_j}U(t)e_j$ for all $j=1,\ldots,n$, $t$. Then $\gamma(t)=\sum_j| u_j(t)\rangle\langle u_j(t)|$ and each of these $u_j(t)$ satisfies (2).

Again, this is straightforward: on the one hand
\begin{align*}
\sum_j|u_j(t)\rangle\langle u_j(t)|&=\sum_j r_j|U(t)e_j\rangle\langle U(t)e_j|\\
&=U(t)\Big(\sum_j r_j|e_j\rangle\langle e_j|\Big)U(t)^*=U(t)D_0U(t)^*=\gamma(t)
\end{align*}
and on the other hand
$$
i\dot u_j(t)=\sqrt{r_j}i\dot U(t)e_j\overset{(4)}= \sqrt{r_j}H(t)U(t)e_j=H(t)\big( \sqrt{r_j}U(t)e_j \big)=H(t)u_j(t)\,.\tag*{$\square$}
$$
Finally, let us conduct a quick sanity check by verifying that this result reproduces what we found in the above example (3).
There
\begin{align*}
\gamma_0&=\frac12\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}=\underbrace{\Big|\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix} \Big\rangle}_{=:u_0}\Big\langle \frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix} \Big|\\
&=\underbrace{\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}}_{=:U_0}\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}}_{=:D_0}\Big(\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}\Big)^*
\end{align*}
so our result says that the (non-trivial) eigenvector of $\gamma(t)$ which satisfies the Schrödinger equation are given by
\begin{align*}
u_1(t)=\sqrt1 U(t)e_1=e^{-i\sigma_zt}U_0e_1=e^{-i\sigma_zt}\psi_0=\begin{pmatrix}e^{-it}&0\\0&e^{it}\end{pmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}=\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix} e^{-it}\\e^{it}\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
which reproduces (3), as expected.

Comment: This is great - thank you! Do you require $u$ maps to $C^{d}$ for $d\geq 2$ to find a counterexample?

Comment: Indeed, regularity of $u$ does not matter: I've added a remark after Eq.(3) which generalizes the counterexample to state vectors $u(t)$ which can even be non-differentiable and only [absolutely continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Equivalent_definitions). I hope this clarifies things :)

Comment: Thanks, that is great. But what I meant to ask was whether we need $u$ to be vector-valued? What happens if $u$ maps only to the complex numbers $\mathbb C$?

Comment: I see; I interpreted your "$C^d$" not as $\mathbb C^d$ but rather "$d$-times differentiable"; my bad! Indeed the counterexample extends to $d=1$ (that is, $u(t)\in\mathbb C$). I edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Why must the density be 1 in this case?

Comment: A density matrix in particular has to have [trace one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix#Definition_and_motivation). But in one dimension ("$1\times1$-matrix") the trace just returns the number itself, meaning $1={\rm tr}(\rho)=\rho$